# Index Out of Bounds in Linq.Enumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I've been getting this error intermittently in a service I'm working on

> Message: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ExceptIterator>d__99`1.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 index)

The code looks like this:

```
List<ApplicationNames> originalApplicationNames = new List<ApplicationNames>(copyOfCachedVersions.Keys.ToList());
var exceptNames = applicationNames.Except( originalApplicationNames );
if (exceptNames != null && exceptNames.ElementAtOrDefault(0) != default(ApplicationNames))
```

Basically, the if statement is supposed to check if exceptNames has any elements. I've already tried using exceptNames.Count() > 0 and exceptNames.Any(), and I get the same error message. I've also tried

```
var exceptNames = applicationNames.Except( originalApplicationNames ).ToList();
```

With the same results

I'm really stuck at this point, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like the error may be produced elsewhere.  How is `applicationNames` defined?

Comment: Not related the question, `exceptNames.ElementAtOrDefault(0) != default(ApplicationNames)` Simpler `exceptNames.Any()`.

Comment: Is `applicationNames` being changed by another thread?

Comment: lomed is right. Also, `exceptNames != null` is pointless; your entire `if` condition should be `exceptNames.Any()`, unless you actually storing that first element in another variable first.

Comment: I've seen this issue when using parallel or asynchronous updates to the list.  Not sure if you are doing that or not.

Comment: @lomed fyi: From op's question, "I've already tried using exceptNames.Count() > 0 and exceptNames.Any()"

Comment: application names is a static object, so several threads would have access to it simultaneously. However, there is locking in place to prevent them from modifying it concurrently

Comment: @JohnPeters +1; yes, "me too"

Comment: @Darendal, color us suspicious on the quality of that locking code...

Comment: I'm not sure that this could be anything other than a locking issue. I'd double check anywhere it's being accessed.

Comment: As first step in debugging I'd clone `applicationNames` into local list and call `.Except` on the copy. This way it will be clear where things are falling apart (which is probably in `applicationNames = Process.GetProcesses()=>p.ProcessName` or something similarly dynamic that does not return the same result on re-iteration).

Comment: Question needs to be updated to make it clear this `copyOfCachedVersions` or `applicationNames` is accessed by multiple threads at the same time, and also post that locking code. Agreed that the problem is probably there.

Comment: Do you get the same stacktrace when you run it with `ToList()` on the `exceptNames` variable? I expect a different one...

Comment: one thing to remember about linq: Stuff doesn't happen when you think it does. If you go lock;linq;unlock the real linq works will be done after the unlock. YOu have to force he linq work to be done by doing .ToList() or .ToArray()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `applicationNames` is a static object, so several threads would have access to it simultaneously. However, there is locking in place to prevent them from modifying it concurrently

When a collection can be modified and read at the same time, it is not enough to prevent concurrent modification. You need to prevent reads that happen concurrently with modification, otherwise you would see random exceptions.

You can work around this by making a copy of `applicationNames`:

```
private static IList<ApplicationNames> ApplicationNamesSync {
    get {
        // Use the same synchronization that prevents concurrent modifications
        lock (appNamesLock) {
            return applicationNames.ToList(); // Make a copy
        }
    }
}
```

Now your code will work:

```
List<ApplicationNames> originalApplicationNames = new List<ApplicationNames>(copyOfCachedVersions.Keys.ToList());
var exceptNames = ApplicationNamesSync.Except( originalApplicationNames );
if (exceptNames != null && exceptNames.ElementAtOrDefault(0) != default(ApplicationNames)) {
    ...
}
```