# Check if IEnumerable<object> has any values inside without getting IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, ienumerable, indexoutofrangeexception

I have a `IEnumerable<object>`. I would like to check if the `IEnumerable<object>` has any values inside.

My method looks like this:

```
private static JObject TransformExcelDatasource(Stream originalDatasource)
{
            // Read Excel Data
            var excelReader = new ExcelReader(originalDatasource);
            var sheetReader = excelReader[0];

            //Check if row has any values
            var row = sheetReader.Row(100);
            var rowHasValues = row.Any();
            if (rowHasValues)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
}
```

I try to get the 100th row of a excel sheet which only has 3 rows. I know that, this is just a POC.

The line `var rowHasValues = row.Any();` throws `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'`

This is how the variable `IEnumerable<object>` `row` looks like:
[image]

I tried answers from this questions ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575358/ienumerable-indexoutofrangeexception), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277534/index-out-of-bounds-in-linq-enumerable)), but nothing worked for me.

**How can I Check if the `IEnumerable<object>` `row` has any values without getting a IndexOutOfRangeException?**

**UPDATE**

This is the IndexOutOfRangeException thrown
[image: ![enter image description here]

`row.Current` is also not a option since it `IEnumerable<object>` doesn't contain it.
[image]

Full Stacktrace:

```
   at LightWeightExcelReader.SheetReader.get_Item(String cellAddress)
   at LightWeightExcelReader.SheetReader.<get_Item>b__8_1(String x)
   at System.Linq.Utilities.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at NR.DataAdapter.Core.Services.TransformDatasourceService.TransformExcelDatasource(Stream originalDatasource) in C:\Dev\src\ipa-dataadapter\NR.DataAdapter.Core\Services\TransformDatasourceService.cs:line 35
   at NR.DataAdapter.Core.Services.TransformDatasourceService.TransformDatasource(IDatasource interpretedDatasource) in C:\Dev\src\ipa-dataadapter\NR.DataAdapter.Core\Services\TransformDatasourceService.cs:line 19
   at NR.DataAdapter.Core.DataAdapter.AdaptDatasources() in C:\Dev\src\ipa-dataadapter\NR.DataAdapter.Core\DataAdapter.cs:line 24
   at NR.DataAdapter.UI.Controllers.HomeController.Dashboard() in C:\Dev\src\ipa-dataadapter\NR.DataAdapter.UI\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 24
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

Comment: It's worth noting (from your picture) that row is a SelectListIterator.  I'm really surprised that `row.Any()` throws.  But (also from your picture), you could try `row.Current != null`

Comment: Looking at your picture again.  Are you sure that `row.Any()` is throwing?  Do you not get the exception if you don't expand the `Results View` in the debug helper?

Comment: @Flydog57 i will update the question with the answers to your questions

Comment: @Nightscape Please [edit] your question to include the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: You might also try changing the declaration of `row` from `IEnumerable<object>` to `var`.  By coercing the type of the variable (to an interface rather than the actual type), you may end up calling an incorrect implementation of `Any`

Comment: @Flydog57 updated code with 'var' and added screenshot

Comment: @Progman added stacktrace to question

Comment: The variable `row` may be an `IEnumerable<object>`.  However, the object to which `row` refers is a `SelectListIterator<LongTypeName, object>`.  It appears to have a `Current` property.  Change your declaration of `row` to `var row = sheetReader.Row(100);` and I bet `.Current` will work.

Comment: @Flydog57 you lost the bet :D I updated the answer with a screenshot of the exception while using 'var'. Here the screenshot, if can't find it in the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJN18.png

Comment: Is `LightWeightExcelReader` from an open source project? If so, you should probably bring this up with them. This isn't a problem with `IEnumerable<object>` specifically. The call to `Row` seems to be calling `Select`, which calls an indexer on something called `SheetReader` in the method passed to it, which itself throws the exception.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson it as a open source framework (https://github.com/ChrisHodges/LightweightExcelReader). I will create a Issue :)

Comment: What do I owe you.  That's weird.  If you look at your first screen shot, `row` has a public property named `Current`.  That's an expected property of an `IEnumerator<T>` (note that that is different than `IEnumerable<T>`) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1.current).  Perhaps if you called `GetEnumerator` on `row` and then `Current` on what is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can check the MaxRow property, before trying to access the Row index.

```
private static JObject TransformExcelDatasource(Stream originalDatasource)
{
    // Read Excel Data
    var excelReader = new ExcelReader(originalDatasource);
    var sheetReader = excelReader[0];

    // Check if the row is not out of limits.
    if (sheetReader.MaxRow < 100) return null;

    // Check if row has any values
    var row = sheetReader.Row(100);
    var rowHasValues = row.Any();
    if (rowHasValues)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, you solved my problem, still the question remains, why the .Any() throws a IndexOutOfRangeException. Like some guys noted in the comments, it's safe that it is a bug from the framework i am using. I will create a issue in there repository

Comment: I took a look at the code. I see that the "Row(100)" method simply returns the Linq query "CellRef.Range(topLeft, bottomRight).Select(x => x.ToString()).Select(x => this[x])". The execution of this Linq query (as usual) is delayed until something tries to iterate.

Basically, the "Any()" tries to iterate over the collection, therefore, it executes the Linq query.

Comment: Looking at the delayed expression, the ".Select(x => this[x])" part is the culprit. It calls "this[string cellAddress]", which throws an "IndexOutOfRangeException" in case "cellRef.Row > WorksheetDimension.BottomRight.Row", which would be the case if you try to access a row that is out of bounds.

Not sure if it can be considered a bug... but I agree that it is not intuitive to have the exception being delayed.

Comment: Author of [LightweightExcelReader](https://github.com/ChrisHodges/LightweightExcelReader) here. I'd agree with DarkCompiled in his approach - check the `MaxRow` property of the SheetReader before trying to access the row index. And yes, this isn't quite a bug, but it's certainly not intuitive that an exception is thrown when you call `Any()` on the enumerable. I've made a change for [version 0.1.15-beta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LightweightExcelReader/0.1.15-beta) so that an `IndexOutOfRangeException` throws when you call `SheetReader.Row()` rather than on evaluation of the enumerable.